# Send each VNC connection to a separate display

Tags: centos, vnc

I want to use `vncserver` on a CentOS 7 server to send every new connected user to their own isolated display (virtual, not physical).

Making virtual displays at server startup with the matching number of VNC servers degrades performance.

What are alternative ways to send every new connected user to their own isolated virtual display?

Answer (score 2):

Just start the VNC server from inet or something equivalent (xinetd, systemd, ...).

On receiving a network connection, start it with option `-inetd`, and whatever other options you want (geometry, authentication, ...),

```
/usr/bin/Xvnc -inetd ...
```

Comment: The best way to use Xvnc -inetd is to use it against an XDMCP-capable display manager.  I use lightdm for that. So I run a systemd service (and socket) that runs “Xvnc -inetd -query localhost -once”.